# Temporary address in Germany

Tags: germany, berlin, mail

I have a long Europe vacation. Since my flights are to/from Berlin, and Germany is in the middle of my trips, I was thinking to get a temporary postal address (e.g., P.O. Box) to receive some materials while I am mobile.

Is there such service in Germany/Berlin?

If yes, how can I get a postal box? Considering the fact that I do not speak Germany, and official paperwork should not be easy.

Answer (score 9):

For letters (but not always parcels), you can also use [general delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante). In Germany, it's called “[Postlagernd](http://www.deutschepost.de/de/p/postlagernd.html)”.

You don't need to do any paperwork beforehand but you need to check that a given post office offers this service and find the correct postal code using [this website](http://www.deutschepost.de/plzsuche/). You will then have the person sending you mail use the following address:

```
[Your name]
Postlagernd
[Postal Code] [City]
```

Letters from Germany are kept for 14 days, letters from abroad for one month.

Answer (score 4):

Close to the German-Swiss border, there are plenty of those services (Google for "lieferadresse deutschland"). They are designed for Swiss customers who order stuff in the EU and can have it delivered to a EU-adress, which is faster and cheaper. You usually get an email when something has arrived, and you pay a few euros per parcel/letter.

In Berlin, without any non-EU country in the vicinity, there aren't that many. I found [one here](http://www.mbe-de.de/geschaeftskunden/weitere-services/postfachservice/) and [also here](http://www.lagerbox.com/pages/de/postfaecher.php) - no prices given unfortunately.